# how to make gdb stop execution when no current breakpoint is avaiable

Tags: gdb

for example,  my code is :

```
int main(){
    f();
    g();
    while(1){
        h();
    }
    ..
 }
```

I set break point on f, g.   of course, the program will stop at f()/g(),  but when I type "c" and then it will keep running.   currently I have to type "CTL+C" to stop it.  program also be killed.

is there any other graceful ways to exit from gdb without killing program if the program is running?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have to type "CTL+C" to stop it. program also be killed.

type "CTL+C" then gdb will catch SIGINT, then type `detach` and then "Ctrl-D" or `quit`. gdb will detach from you process and exit. Your program will go on running and its parent process will become `init` (PID=1)

---

Update:

```
(gdb) info signals SIGINT
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes       Yes     No              Interrupt
```

Comment: First ctrl+c will actually be caught by gdb.

Comment: Thanks your suggestions.   but no idea why CTL+C doesn't work for me. but CTL+Z works. (gdb) d breakpoints 
Delete all breakpoints? (y or n) y
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C

[New Thread 0x7f71b4b09700 (LWP 2277)]
[Thread 0x7f71b4b09700 (LWP 2277) exited]
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gdb -p 21942
[root@lvs2b1c-93cb mongo_dev]# ps -ef | grep mongod
root      2280 22493  0 22:22 pts/3    00:00:00 grep mongod
root     21942     1  0 19:52 ?        00:00:04 /data/mongo-9923/bin/mongod -f /opt/mongo_conf/mongod.conf

Comment: @zhihuifan, Please execute `info signals SIGINT` in gdb. On my computer its output I added to the answer.

Comment: @zhihuifan, Please, look at this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/why-didnt-ctrl-c-work

Comment: Thanks skwllsp. <blink> (gdb)  info signals SIGINT`
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes       Yes     No              Interrupt
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C[New Thread 0x7f4407008700 (LWP 13040)]
[Thread 0x7f4407008700 (LWP 13040) exited]

[Thread 0x7f440980c700 (LWP 12905) exited]
`[Thread 0x7f440a20d700 (LWP 12904) exited]
^C</blink>

Comment: @zhihuifan, Have you managed to send Ctrl-C to your application after reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/why-didnt-ctrl-c-work?

Comment: my debug process is mongod.  I don't know how mongod handle ctl+c.  but when I type clt+c in gdb, what action will be taken should be decided in gdb, not mongod in this case.  do I understand right?

Comment: @zhihuifan, with your setting for SIGINT - yes, in gdb